# toLeftOf resource not found

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I've used toLeftOf many times before but it suddenly stopped working. I tried:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/spacer"
```

Here is the view:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/spacer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/center_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/center_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/center_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/center_margin" />
```

And it gave me the errors:

```
Error:(16, 34) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_toLeftOf' with value '@id/spacer').
Error:(17, 35) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_toStartOf' with value '@id/spacer').
```

It works at other points in the app but for some reason it doesn't work here. Anyone know whats wrong?

Edit - Yes it is in a RelativeLayout. Here is a condensed version:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt1" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/spacer" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That `View` is probably not contained by a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Can you please post the whole layout?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Upon further review I figured out the issue is I was trying to reference the View before it was made. I fixed this by changing @id/spacer to @+id/spacer

Comment: Please mark the answer to the question then, if it occurred here.

Comment: Thank you! I just rand into the same problem and your fix fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but maybe still helpful for others. Took me 1 hour to find out my issue.

Non working example:

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstview"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/secondview"/>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondview"/>
```

Working example

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstview"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/secondview"/>

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/secondview"/>
```

Not the sign "+" being the only difference.
If you reference a view which is defined after the view you put the reference in, you need to use a +

Comment: I keep forgetting that you have to add the +, weird tho that it only needs to be done once... Believe its mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Write the layout which is used as refrence, then the layout you want to put relative to that layout...

It's  like trying to use variable before it was declared in the same class file.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot reference a property that is not found in your respective ViewGroup. In this case you are trying to access properties that are specific to RelativeLayout. You cannot access these kinds of properties UNLESS your encapsulating view is in fact a RelativeLayout.

Note that this applies to the Parent layout that the view is encapsulated in.